# C programming for arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to c language and having some trouble in a program.I have 3 arrays
size = 8;

```
 u8 a [size]; // a = 0x0D
    u8 b [size]; // b= 0xDE
    u16 new_buffer[size]; // i want to see as 0xDE0D on the terminal
```

I need to move the contents of a as Lower order byte and contents of b as higher order byte in the new_buffer and later right shift the the new_buffer by three bits. I read about it and was suggested to use two for loops. I tried it but not getting appropriate output.
please help me for this..

```
u8 SendBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
u8 RecvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
u16 Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 

int main(void) { 
    RecvBuffer[0] = 0x00; 
    RecvBuffer[1] = 0x0D; 

    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) { 
        return XST_FAILURE; 
    } 
    printf("Sensor data is = 0x%x \n\r", RecvBuffer[0]); 
    printf("---Data received successfully---\n\r"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have tried? Showing the attempt you have made will often result in more helpful and forthcoming answers

Comment: u8 SendBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
u8 RecvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
u16 Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int main(void)

{
        RecvBuffer[0] = 0x00;
 RecvBuffer[1] = 0x0D;
 
 if (Status != XST_SUCCESS)
 {
  return XST_FAILURE;
 }
 
 printf("Sensor data is = 0x%x \n\r", RecvBuffer[0]);
        printf("---Data received successfully---\n\r");
 return 0;
}

Comment: Arghhh, edit the question, that code you posted as a comment is really ugly.

Comment: The original question makes no sense in the light of the added code, where the two buffers have nothing to do with each other. Did you want to merge `RecvBuffer[0]` with `RecvBuffer[1]` to make a 16-bit value?

Answer (score 2):

Two versions here, depending on the endian-ness

```
for (i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    // little endian
    new_buffer[i] = (u16)a[i] << 8 | (u16)b[i]); 

    // big endian
    new_buffer[i] = (u16)b[i] << 8 | (u16)a[i]);

    // bit shift
    new_buffer[i] >>= 3;
}
```

Or, to rotate the buffer 3 bits to the right

```
u16 bits, prev = 0;
for (i=0; i<BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    bits = new_buffer[i];
    new_buffer[i] = bits >> 3 | prev;
    prev = bits << (sizeof(u16)*8 - 3);
}
```

Comment: Good point!!, I missed the endianness, but why the `>> 3`? I don't get this.

Comment: @AlterMann because OP says *"and later right shift the the `new_buffer` by three bits"* (but he could have meant *" and flow through to the next element"*).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. it made the idea clear to me now. N sorry for posting the code as comment, i am new to this forum so wasnt able to use it properly, now I will try this idea to my program to get the correct output

Comment: I tried the above code in my program and the new buffer data is 0x27FB and the shifted data is 0x278C. What could be the problem? plz help

Comment: @nsh I rejected your proposed edit, but what you tried  was `New_Buffer_Shifted[i] >>= 3; xil_printf("Shifted data by 3 bits is  = 0x%x \n\r", New_Buffer);` - you didn't print the shifted var.

Comment: I was supposed to ask the question but by mistake edited the post. well I retried the new variable xil_printf("Shifted data by 3 bits is = 0x%x \n\r", New_Buffer_Shifted) but still getting the same output????

Comment: Perhaps time to ask a new question, showing the code that is not working, as this one did rather change course?

Comment: the output is not correct, in a im getting 0xC and b= 0xC but the new_buffer is 0X2860. whould should I chnage

Answer (score 1):

Note that `u8` is not part of the standard, you mean `uintX_t`, and these values are not arrays but variables:

```
uint8_t a = 0X0D;
uint8_t b = 0XDE;
uint16_t new_buffer = ((uint16_t)b << 8) | a;
```

As pointed out by @WeatherVane, you need to reverse those values if you are under big endian:

```
uint16_t new_buffer = ((uint16_t)a << 8) | b;
```

Comment: I m programming in Xilinx SDK, so u8 its unsigned 8 bit integer, the output im getting is 2 8 bit hex data, as 0D and DE i want to see them as complete 16 bit data in one named new_buffer

Comment: This is exactly what @AlterMann has provided here. Just change `uint8_t` to `u8` and `uint16_t` to `u16`

Comment: Thanks. In general can u plz guide me by a rough example, I have 2 8 bit variables, and have to copy that in a 16 bit variable. how to do that? and how can I move the data of a variable to left or right? I read the book but getting some confusions. It would be kind if i get just a random example to clear my conecpt.